# I can't upgrade a package in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  dell-linux-assistant
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Can someone please tell me what to do? I'm new to Ubuntu and I have no idea what that means.

I did `sudo apt upgrade` and it shows that I have 0 upgrades, but with the command `sudo apt-get upgrade` it shows me this.

Also, if you recommend any book or a course to learn more about Ubuntu it will be appreciated.

Comment: for beginners to Unix/Linux, I've recommended John Muster's Unix Made Easy.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it

Answer (score 1):

This [Q\A on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it) explain the meaning of `The following packages have been kept back` message:

> If the dependencies have changed on one of the packages you have installed so that a new package must be installed to perform the upgrade then that will be listed as "kept-back".

Run:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

**Book recommendation:** You can install the `debian-handbook` package:

```
sudo apt install debian-handbook
```

It can be accessed offline. In your browser enter this URL:

```
file:///usr/share/doc/debian-handbook/html/en-US/index.html
```

To see the available translations:

```
ls /usr/share/doc/debian-handbook/html/
```

E,g: To display the French translation, use this URL:

```
file:///usr/share/doc/debian-handbook/html/fr-FR/index.html
```